# time.h - struct tm and milliseconds

Tags: c

I have log data ranging from 1000 to 100000 entries all from different sources. The objective is to sort this data by time (quickly). I was prototyping in C and i'm stuck because it looks like tm doesn't support milliseconds. Am i missing something here ? Any suggestions ?

Idea:

1. Open file. Parse line-by-line and tokenize fields to c struct via strtok

   1.1 Convert Date & Time to "struct tm".

   1.2 Build linked list
2. Sort linked list based on time (don't know which sort algorithm i'd use)
3. Output

[Example]

```
YYYY-MM-DD,HH:MM:SS:MS , PID, TID , COMPONENT, Message 
2017-03-29,20:56:27:088, 3436,2568,COMPONENT, Message String blah blah
2017-03-29,20:56:27:089, 3436,2568,COMPONENT, Message String baaaaa
2017-03-29,20:56:27:079, 3436,2568,COMPONENT, Message String roarrr
2017-03-29,20:56:28:061, 3436,2568,COMPONENT, Message String meow
2017-03-29,20:56:25:044, 3436,2568,COMPONENT, Message String ruff ruff 
.
.
.
100000 entries
```

---

```
const char T[] = "2017-03-29,20:56:27:088"; //Test String
time_t result = 0;
int year = 0, month = 0, day = 0;
int hour = 0, min = 0, sec = 0, ms = 0;

if (sscanf(T, "%4d-%2d-%2d,%2d:%2d:%2d", &year, &month, &day, &hour, &min, &sec) == 6) {
    struct tm tv = {0};
    tv.tm_year = year;
    tv.tm_mon = month;
    tv.tm_mday = day;
    tv.tm_hour = hour;
    tv.tm_min = min;
    tv.tm_sec = sec;
    //Crap, it doesn't look like tm handles milliseconds ????

    if ((result = mktime(&tv)) == (time_t)-1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Conversion Error\n");
    }
    puts(ctime(&result));
}
else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid Format\n");
}
```

Comment: C++ has a [chrono's high_resolution_clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) whose duration you can cast to milliseconds as easy as _"A, B, C, 1, 2, 3"_. That being said please consider removing the `c++` tag from your C question. They are two different languages.

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  They are different languages.

Comment: Check repo: https://github.com/izaak-coleman/chronoBench. If you can use C++, you can use this.

Comment: From C++17 you can use timespec_get: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/timespec_get which retrieves a timespec http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/timespec which contains a field for nanoseconds

Comment: Have you tried your Operating System `sort` utility (if available)? ... or why not sort text?

Comment: In C, all the clocks with a higher resolution than 1 second granularity are somewhat system dependent, and there are frequently a myriad options available.  Very often, the integral seconds part is based on the `time_t` that can be converted to `struct tm`.  The subseconds part be based on milliseconds, microseconds or nanoseconds (and probably others).  POSIX is headed in the direction of 'nanoseconds for subseconds' but still has legacy interfaces using other resolutions.  However, you have to fix the formatting for subsecond data.

Comment: C11 does specify a `struct timespec` (§7.27.1 **Date and time `<time.h>`**) which is compatible with POSIX `struct timespec` and supports nanosecond resolution.  The function to get the current time in a `struct timespec` is `timespec_get()`.  C11 doesn't mandate that `struct tm` has a subsecond component, and `strftime()` has no way to format subsecond components, etc.

Comment: Hello @NathanOliver, i'm using C.... the C++ tag was added by mistake.. and i don't know how to remove it. New to stackoverflow.

Comment: @Matt No problem.  It has been fixed.

Comment: Did you try the command line program [sort](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html). It may well do good job without you needing to write code for it. `$ cat file1.log file2.log file3.log|sort > sorted.logs`

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand why you need to convert those timestamps into a `struct tm`, or into any other representation. They will already lexicographically sort just the way you want, in their current string form. So just do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can take the result you get back from `mktime` and convert it to milliseconds.

```
if ((result = mktime(&tv)) == (time_t)-1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Conversion Error\n");
}
long long resultmilli = (result * 1000LL) + ms;
```